# Make ruby model work with generated route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing

So before you say it, I have read through this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and also I'm using Rails 3.2.13

I have defined wiki in my routes file as a resource and should therefore get the generated routing functions such as wiki_path() etc. I read in the above article that if a route function is defined, and you pass in an object, it can figure out the id based if it responds to the id method which all ActiveRecord classes do.

Here's my problem, my Wiki class does not inherit from ActiveRecord, and though I've defined the id function as below, the router is still passing in the entire wiki object as the id parameter.

```
def id 
  url_id = wiki.slug
  url_id ||= wiki.title
  url_id
end
```

The error I get is this when I try to create a new wiki:

**ActionController::RoutingError at /wiki/what-is-the-meaning-of-life**

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"wiki", 
:id=>#<Wiki:0x007f92a6793700 @user=nil, @path_to_repo="wiki.git", 
@wiki=#<Gollum::Wiki:70133917472560 wiki.git>, @page=nil, @persisted=false, 
  @attributes={"title"=>"what-is-the-meaning-of-life"}>}
```

I want the :id to be the return value of the id function in the Wiki class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `to_param` method, not `id`:

```
def to_param 
  wiki.slug || wiki.title
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! +1 for making my method more elegant with the || op. ;)